# Find tag with id including [] with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nokogiri

I have an html element like:

```
<div id="spam[500]">
```

I want to search for this element by id, but it seems that nokogiri is getting confused by the []. I'm trying:

```
doc.css("#spam[#{eggs.id}]")
```

but to no avail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Chris, try this and let me know if it works:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page)
el = doc.xpath("//div[@id='spam[500]']").first
```

The problem is that you can't access it via CSS (even in the browser).  Try setting some CSS attributes for "spam[500]" and they won't be applied.  You can access via xpath however, as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here is that the characters [ and ] are illegal in an HTML4 (or XML) id attribute - look at the following:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

(for the normative definition of the id attribute look at www.w3.org//TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id)

Answer (score 1):

you can also do it this way

```
el = doc.xpath("id(spam[500])").first
```

for elements having id's you can call them directly through id because its always unique.

for finding out xpaths, please add a 'xpath checker' plugin to firefox. It helps a lot and very easy