# How can I use Nokogiri to get value inside element with certain id?

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

I have an element structure consisting of item nodes that I parse like this with Nokogiri:

```
@xml.css('item').each do |item|
    # do something
end
```

Now the item has a part which looks like this 9every item has this element with the id below):

```
<customfield id="customfield_10004" key="com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:float">
    <customfieldname>Yada yada</customfieldname>
    <customfieldvalues>
        <customfieldvalue>8.0</customfieldvalue>
    </customfieldvalues>
</customfield>
```

I want to parse the 8.0 value from this. In another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235774/find-tag-with-id-including-with-nokogiri) I found that you can use something like this (for HTML):

```
item.xpath("//customfield[@id='customfield_10004']").css('customfieldvalue')
```

Unfortunately, this seems to return a string of all values in the same order, and not the specific one to the item node I am looking at.

Does anyone know how to parse the float value in the customfieldvalue node?

Comment: Beware [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you're using `//` at the beginning of your xpath query, which is telling the xpath engine to start at the root of the document and find everything that matches, regardless of your current node. Try using `./` instead.

Comment: Thank, but does not return anything when I use `./`. `puts story.xpath("./customfield[@id='customfield_10004']")` returns nothing. Is item not what I think it is?

Comment: The syntax is `.//`. Two slashes after the dot!

Answer (score 2):

Try using an XPath expression to identify the element and extract the text of the first matching node:

```
@xml.xpath('//item').each do |item|
  path = "//customfield[@id='customfield_10004']/*/customfieldvalue"
  item.xpath(path).first.text.to_f // => 8.0, etc
end
```

Comment: There can be more than one customfieldvalue. Ah, your edit addresses that. But still I think it returns all values and not the 1 specific to the item I am in? And the path value is not correct, returns an error.

Comment: That code will print the float value of the text inside the first "customfieldvalue" element inside the first "customfield" element with id "customfield_10004".

Comment: Thanks. There can be more than one id "customfield_10004". Every item has one. So this does not work since we get all items. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: If you run that code separately for each item then it shouldn't matter that each item has a node with the same id, right?

Comment: But the answer above says that `//` starts at the root of the document? Or are you making a new xml for each item? The code does not work, there comes a parser error from Nokogiri in the path variable.